# Function in Angular factory is undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have the following [preloader.js](https://github.com/dabit3/angular-easy-image-preloader/blob/master/preloader.js) factory file included in my project.

```
    angular.module('movieSeat')
        .factory('preloader', function( $q, $rootScope ) {
```

In my controller I inject the factory as following:

```
    angular.module('movieSeat')
        .controller('moviesearchCtrl', ['$scope', 'moviesearchFactory', function ($scope, moviesearchFactory, preloader) {
```

When I try to use the `preloadImages` function inside the preload controller:

```
    $scope.imageLocations = [
        "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300_and_h450_bestv2//nlqFgG7jfBITl8fJHzL72jXwYLt.jpg",
        "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300_and_h450_bestv2//ghL4ub6vwbYShlqCFHpoIRwx2sm.jpg",
        "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300_and_h450_bestv2//weUSwMdQIa3NaXVzwUoIIcAi85d.jpg",
    ];

    preloader.preloadImages($scope.imageLocations)
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'preloadImages' of undefined

If I comment out the `preloader.preloadImages($scope.imageLocations)` code the error is gone. So to me it looks like injecting the preloader factory in my controller works fine but I can't figure out why I can't call the function `preloadImages` on the `preload` factory.

Comment: show us the preloadImages function

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in the dependency injection list. You forgot to add `preloader` in the list of dependency strings.

```
 .controller('moviesearchCtrl', ['$scope', 'moviesearchFactory', 'preloader' /*here*/, function ($scope, moviesearchFactory, preloader) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference your factory/service 'preloader' in your controller call as follows:

```
angular.module('movieSeat')
        .controller('moviesearchCtrl', ['$scope', 'moviesearchFactory', 'preloader', function ($scope, moviesearchFactory, preloader) {

})
```